# pandas dataframe error in demographic data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am analyzing a dataset and do not want to drop males from the dataset.

````
```data['Gender']=data['Gender'].str.strip()
```data['Gender']  =np.where( data['Gender'] == "F", 0,1) 
```data['Gender'] =data['Gender'].astype(float)

how can I change this code to include males and females?
````

Comment: Please show an example of what your desired output would look like so you can get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

Use a dictionary to map column values. For example

```
dict_map = {'F': 0, 'M':1}
data['Gender'] = data['Gender'].map(dict_map)
```

Comment: Thank you Jesse, would you recommend this approach even if I were using this for dataframe like this?

```#Demographic
```ds=pd.read_csv("E:\Data Science\BIO\Data set\demo_data.csv")

```#Select demographic data
```data=ds[['Seq ID', 'CHTN ID','Smoking', 'Gender', 'Race', 'Age','BMI', "Group", ```"Histology Group"]]

```data=data[data["Gender"]!="M"]
```data['Gender']=data['Gender'].str.strip()
```data['Gender']  =np.where( data['Gender'] == "F", 0,1) 
```data['Gender'] =data['Gender'].astype(float)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your desired output but perhaps [get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

Data:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "Gender": ["M", "F", "F", "M", "M"],
    "Name": ["Joe", "Mary", "Tina", "Bob", "Tony"]
})
```

Code:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(data=df, columns=["Gender"], dtype="int", prefix="", prefix_sep="")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Name  F  M
0   Joe  0  1
1  Mary  1  0
2  Tina  1  0
3   Bob  0  1
4  Tony  0  1
```